# Как нарисовать такую фигуру на D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Подскажите, как её нарисовать не используя две фигуры. Так же известен радиус, высота и расстояние между верхней точкой окружности и верхним ребром прямоугольника.

Моя реализация:

```
this.svg.append("circle")      
    .attr("cx", 45)           
    .attr("cy", 299)           
    .attr("r", 35)
    .style("stroke", "green")
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke-width', 3);
this.svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', 10) 
    .attr('y', 300) 
    .attr('width',70) 
    .attr('height', 70)
    .attr('stroke', 'green')
    .attr('fill', 'white')
    .style("stroke", "green")
    .attr('stroke-width', 3);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MaximLensky, комментарий ради комментария

Comment: @MaximLensky, я согласен с этим. Но вопрос в другом.

Comment: а можно еще попросить как то отметить на рисунке исходные величины. А то не совсем понятно..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 тут весьма сбоку и пригодится только доля DOM манипуляций.

Все что необходимо, это составить примерно вот такой `path`

`<path d="M200,100v100h-100v-100A50,50,0,0,1,200,100">`.

---

Перечислю все команды в порядке их использования в пути:

`M100,100` идем в точку `200 100`

`v100` чертим вертикальную линию на `100` **вниз** от текущей точки

`h-100` чертим горизонтальную линию на `100` **влево** от текущей точки

`v-100` чертим вертикальную линию на `100` **вверх** от текущей точки

`A50,50,0,0,1,200,100` чертим [дугу](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) радиусом по `x` и по `y` равным `50` и с окончанием в точке `200 100`

Аргументы команды `arc`:  `rx, ry, x-axis-rotation, large-arc-flag, sweep-flag, x, y`

---

Вот иллюстрация как работают 3 флага в аргументах дуги (`x-axis-rotation, large-arc-flag, sweep-flag`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
shape(35, 100, 30, 60);    
shape(125, 100, 30, 90);  
shape(235, 100, 50, 60);
shape(325, 100, 10, 60); 
shape(375, 100, 10, 160); 
shape(475, 100, 35, 110); 

// x центра, y центра, радиус, общая высота
function shape(cx, cy, r, h) {
  
  let dy = cy + r/2 - h/2;
  
  let d = `
    M${cx+r},${dy}
    v${h} h${-r*2} v${-h}
    a${r},${r},0,0,1,${r*2},0 
  `;

  svg = d3.select('svg');

  svg.append("path")      
      .attr("stroke", "green")
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke-width', 3)
      .attr('d', d);
  
  // все ниже нужно только для подсказок
  svg.append('path')
     .attr("stroke", "red")
     .attr('fill', 'none')
     .attr('marker-start','url(#triangle2r)')
     .attr('marker-end','url(#triangle1r)')
     .attr('d', `M${cx},${dy},v${h}`)
  
  svg.append('path')
     .attr("stroke", "blue")
     .attr('fill', 'none')
     .attr('marker-end','url(#triangle1b)')
     .attr('marker-start','url(#triangle2b)')
     .attr('d', `M${cx},${dy},l${Math.cos(1)*r},-${Math.sin(1)*r}`)
  
  svg.append('circle')
     .attr('cx', cx)
     .attr('cy', cy)
     .attr('r', 2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 200" height="90vh">
   <defs>
    <marker id="triangle1r" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="9" refY="5" 
          markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" orient="auto">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" fill="#f00"/>
    </marker>
    <marker id="triangle2r" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" 
          markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" orient="auto">
      <path d="M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z" fill="#f00"/>
    </marker>
    <marker id="triangle1b" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="9" refY="5" 
          markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" orient="auto">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" fill="#00f"/>
    </marker>
    <marker id="triangle2b" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" 
          markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" orient="auto">
      <path d="M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z" fill="#00f"/>
    </marker>
</defs> 
</svg>
```

Вспомогательные маркеры:

Синяя линия - `r`, красная - `h`, точка - центр фигуры

Comment: Линия под окружностью не нужна. Это важно.

Comment: @doox911 не заметил этого условия =)

Comment: @doox911 изменил ответ, и d3 тут весьма сбоку, я все равно вручную составил path

Comment: А если задан радиус высота и расстояние от верхней точки окружности, до той линии, которую не надо рисовать?

Comment: @doox911 запросто, но только добавьте это в вопрос

Comment: Сделано) И спасибо.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92511/discussion-between-doox911-and-stranger-in-the-q).